# ExtJS Button Style Toolbar

Tags: button, extjs, styles, toolbar

I was wondering if it is possible to put a button into a panel's toolbar but have it retain the look of a button as if it was just in a plain panel.

For example, i want the button to look like this:

[image: Button Style]

However, it looks like this:

[image: Toolbar Button]

Thanks so much!

**EDIT**

Code to create toolbar:

```
xtype: 'toolbar',
        items:
        [
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Select bounding box on map',
                id: 'bbBoxButton',
                icon: 'img/cross_cursor.gif',
                listeners: {
                    click: function(){
                        polygonControl.activate();
                    }
                }   
            }
        ]
```

Code to create regular button:

```
{xtype: 'button',    id: 'bboxButton', text: 'Select bounding box on map', icon: 'img/cross_cursor.gif', listeners: {click: function(){polygonControl.activate()}}}
```

I believe I have to use the cls config for the button, but i cannot seem to find the appropriate css class.

Comment: please include the code which you have tried..

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same issue.  To solve, I pass this into the button:

```
cls:'x-btn-default-small'
```

Comment: Once you rollover the button, won't the class be removed?

Comment: this does not work for IE8

Answer (score 2):

Adding this

```
ctCls: 'x-btn-over'
```

to button config solved the issue for me in Ext 2.2.1